# What is the relationship between a metric and the Frechet structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, frechet-manifold

Let $M$ be a smooth, closed m dimensional manifold. Let $K\subset M$ be a smooth stratifold inside $M$. I'd like to show that $\mathop{Diff}(M,K)$ is a Frechet submanifold of $\mathop{Diff}(M)$. Locally, $\mathop{Diff}(M)$ is modeled on $C^{\infty}(f^{*}TM \rightarrow M)$ where the correspondence between sections $X$ close to the zero section get mapped to a diffeomorphism via the exponential mapping. As noted in [A convenient setting for global analysis](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=l-XxBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=a+convenient+setting+for+global+analysis&ots=hAoFr9RrmX&sig=ee8iexvpPkXoTDnE3y09R0IMc1M#v=onepage&q=a%20convenient%20setting%20for%20global%20analysis&f=false), the choice of metric doesn't influence the structure of $Diff(M)$ (Section 42). So, choose a Metric on $M$ so that $K$ is totally geodesic, i.e., If $X_p$ is tangent to $K$, then $\mathop{exp}_p(tX_p)$ is a geodesic in $K$. Fix this metric.

Now I'll define an open set $U$ around the identity and a closed linear subspace, $\mathcal{K}$ of $C^{\infty}(TM\rightarrow M)$ so that $\mathop{Diff}(M,K) \cap U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal{K}$. Define $\mathcal{K}= \{X ~|~ X\big|_{K} \in TK\}$, i.e $\mathcal{K}$ consist of the sections on $M$ which restrict to sections of $K$. It's easy to see $K$ is a closed linear subspace. More over, by our choice of metric, we have a bijective correspondence between $K$ and $\mathop{Diff}(M,K) \cap U$ provided $U$ is chosen small enough. To get an open set around any point $f\in \mathop{Diff}(M,K)$, one uses that $f_{*}:Diff(M)\rightarrow Diff(M)$ is a homeomorphism.

I'd like to understand if the choice of metric effects whether or not this subgroup (and similar subgroups) are Frechet submanifolds or not.